# plotly-heatmap Why is my graph off the Y-axis

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, plotly, heatmap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3O9Y.png)
The graph is pressed on the Y-axis. How do I solve this problem? I want it to be aligned with the Y-axis

```
 for (let k = 0; k < mouseOriginData.length; k++) {
                mouseOriginData.sort(function (a, b) {
                    return a.submission.cluster - b.submission.cluster
                })
                //mouse所有的配置项
                mouseTrace[k] = {
                    type: 'box',
                    lowerfence: [mouseOriginData[k].submission.c0],
                    q1: [mouseOriginData[k].submission.c25],
                    median: [mouseOriginData[k].submission.c50],
                    q3: [mouseOriginData[k].submission.c75],
                    upperfence: [mouseOriginData[k].submission.c100],
                    y: [mouseOriginData[k].submission.cluster],
                    name: k,
                }
                mouseBoxPlotData.push(mouseTrace[k])
            }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code is the configuration item required by the diagram and makes no sense

Comment: I'm sorry I can't post pictures